# yii2 kartik daterangepicker autoselect end date when start date is clicked

Tags: yii2, daterangepicker, kartik-v

I want to set end `date` the same as start `date` :

```
<?php
        echo $form->field($model, 'date_range', [
            'options' => ['class' => 'drp-container form-group']
        ])->widget(DateRangePicker::classname(), [
            'id' => 'dateRange',
            'convertFormat' => true,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'timePicker' => true,
                'timePicker24Hour' => true,
                'timePickerIncrement' => 1,
                'autodate' => true,
                'minDate' => (string) date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('- 1 month')),
                'maxDate' => (string) date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'singleDatePicker' => false,
                'autoApply' => false,
                'locale' => ['format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s']
            ],
            'pluginEvents' => [
            ],
        ])
        ?>
```

When i try to select end date like this it is not functioning :

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.available', function (e) {
            $('#dateRange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(date);
        })
```

Is it possible to make it work like i want?

Regards!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue? I am also facing the same issue.